# random url from database

Tags: php

I have stored several urls in my mysql, but I want to echo random url from those websites. This seems very simple but it's not. Suppose I have stored www.xyz.com in mysql then I dont want to echo www.xyz.com . If that website consists of 10000 urls then each time I echo that websites I want to display random urls from those 10000 not the home page.

for example mysql consists of

```
www.a1.com
www.a2.com
www.a2.com
```

etc
if in a particular situation the echo tries to display www.a1.comm then it should get any random url from www.a1.com and display it however that url is not there in mysql.

In mysql only homepage is stored.

I have searched several pages, but everywhere I am finding how to display random url from mysql.

Comment: just i am making something so want to test

Comment: If I understand the question, you have a database with (or without) URLs that, if/when you generate a random URL, the generated URL should **not** be contained in this list? What do you mean by "random"? A random set of characters up to length *x*? Or a random *actual* URL?

Comment: *any* random URL? Does it need to return content, or are 404s okay? (e.g. www.a1.com/asdiuywtg87y47tyhsUFha8efy8ry892qw3ryfaw893ry87wzrt is somewhat random, but unlikely to have content)

Comment: @Piskvor you understands correctly . but i will prefer not to 404 but if 404 is coming then also its ok i can filter but the solution you want to give is difficult to implement as out of 1 million trial one correct url will come

Comment: @user1515503: Well, that's what I'm asking about. Do you have some sort of URL map for those domains, or are you trying to guess valid URLs completely from outside?

Comment: @Piskvor i have only homepage and i want to guess from outside but with higher efficiency

Comment: @user1515503: Tough task. Very tough task. Perhaps checking search engines to see what *they* have indexed for the site *might* help; but apart from this, you'd need to spider the site in question yourself (or at least its sitemap, if any) to determine which pages are (in)valid.

Comment: Most websites have a XML sitemap specified in their robots.txt file. You could start with that assumption to crawl them.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   *
FROM     table
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT    0,1;
```

Use `ORDER BY RAND()` to mix them up, then use `LIMIT` to pop one entry off the table.

You can also add `WHERE` clause if you're looking to filter by specific column properties.

References:

- [`RAND()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand)
- [`SELECT ... LIMIT offset,row_count`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Comment: Brad Christie i have cleraly written i know how to get random url from  mysql . i want to display random url which is not stored in mysql .for ex if www.xyz.com is stored then i want to display any valid url from that site not www.xyz.com

Comment: And that is where the `WHERE` clause would come in. To my defense, you've done a very poor job explaining the problem, specifically how you're planning to exclude results and where said exclusions come from. -- EDIT: Instead of saying "I have these urls in a database but I don't want them" how about showing a few rows of data, and what you'd _like_ to return and based on _what criteria_ (is is based on user's current page, a setting in the database/config file, etc.?)

Comment: Brad Christie in table nothing is there otherwise i would have done rand() but in mysql only parent url are there and i am trying to output random url from that website.your code will not work as your code is valid only if the links for that  domain is stored in database but nothing is stored other than parent domain. suppose xyz.com is stored and it is having 1000 webpages so i want to diplay  the webpages for example xyz.com/rrhnnrf/tneernfr/teki.html as output

Comment: @user1515503 How do you expect to get the sitemap of a site using only mysql?

Comment: @Brad Christie  i dont know so i asked

Comment: @user1515503 Indeed, you're looking for a sitemap _assuming_ it can be generated both dynamically and from a database. I think it's time to re-evaluate what you're going for here.